# Django form image choice- widget type

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Ok. I want to make an app that is changing image from model A and save it as new to model B. On the form in template I want visible images to choose. How can I do it?

Model and form A

model

```
from django.db import models


class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

form

```
from django import forms
from .models import Photo


class Photoform(forms.ModelForm):
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('photo',)
```

Model and form B

model

```
from django.db import models


class Meme(models.Model):
    meme = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

form

```
from django import forms
from Uploader.models import Photo


class Memeform(forms.Form):
    meme = forms.ModelChoiceField(Photo.objects.all(), widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('meme',)
```

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method= "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
            <h2>Your image here</h2>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Create</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i have widget RadioSelect, but i need to be images visible to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form.fields["photo"].queryset = Photo.objects.all()` in your views..You can refer more from here..http://www.wkoorts.com/wkblog/2009/08/10/pre-populate-django-modelform-with-specific-queryset/

Answer (score 0):

in your views

```
form.fields["photo"].queryset = Photo.objects.all()
```

You can refer more from.
And in HTML you should write down:

```
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.media }}
```